# Looking for jquery text paging component

Tags: jquery-plugins, paging

Basically it should be comparable to jquery-ui tabs, without the tabs (on top) but with navigation buttons (below) instead (first, prev, next, last). Do you know of such a plugin?

I googled around a bit, could not find anything. It shouldn't be too hard to write myself but it's better to copy something good than too implement something bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Answer (score 1):

dr - how about this one: http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/pager/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: actually, i do tend to include both a link and an excerpt now for this type of answer. an example being my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449711/generating-knockout-markup-in-mvc-3/11451130#11451130 but you make a good point in general and thankfully i've moved on in the few years since this answer :-)